# Text background color in code snippets slightly different color than the area background color

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

It's easiest if I just show a picture.  Screenshot from here: [Flash framerate reliability](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9593/flash-framerate-reliability)

What it looks like on the site: (Chrome, win7)
[image: naked screenshot]

If you can't see it, the background of the areas where there are text are an ever-so-slightly-darker shade of gray.

Image adjusted to exacerbate the effect:
[image: adjusted screenshot]

Is this intentional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have eagle eyes. This was not intentional. I have made both PRE and the CODE to have the same bg. The change will be in the next deployment.

Answer (score 1):

The color difference can really vary depending on the monitor you have, especially between CRT and LCD, and in the case of an LCD monitor, your viewing angle to your monitor. For example on both of my laptops (MacBook Pro and Dell), I certainly wouldn't call that 'ever-so-slightly-darker'; it's quite obviously a different shade than the background.

I did find the region of CSS though. Both in meta and in the main site, code blocks have a deliberate background of #eee: (the following snippet is identical in both CSS files)

```
code{font-family:Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace, serif;color:#222;background-color:#eee;}
```

I'd label it as a feature. I like how it makes the code block stand out, and I think that's the point.

Comment: I think the effect Tetrad was talking about was too subtle for you to notice. It's not the difference between the page background and the code block background. It's the difference between the code block text background and the code block block background.

Comment: OHHH you're right! I see it now! And now I understand the need for the adjusted image too! :)